# When to push for a promotion to be made 'official'?

Tags: promotion, raise, technology

Is there a best time to ask about an official title change/raise following taking over someone else's role (After their resignation)?  I'm currently in the process of taking over tasks that a previous employee handled, whose title (and presumably pay, though I can't confirm that) was a fair bit ahead of my own(average salary of the position in question is ~90% higher than my position's average).  Some of these new responsibilities include effectively being on-call to handle critical issues with our servers, or assisting users past normal business hours.

My direct report has already talked to me about vague plans to have me take over the role, I'm just uncertain at what point I should be pushing for it to be made 'official', with an equal push for a substantial raise to reflect that change.

Comment: How much time have you been with this increased responsibility?

Comment: I don't know if push is the best word, but if your responsibilities change, you are entitled to ask right away for a raise/promotion according to these responsibilities. Then it's just a matter of salary/promotion negotiation which has been discussed in a lot of questions here

Comment: The big unknown to me is if the new job responsibilities justify a promotion. So if 3-4 people are each getting some of the tasks then all of you don't deserve a promotion. Also you can't be expected to suddenly be doing two people's worth of work. So are some of your current tasks being passed to others? That would also be an indication that your overall responsibilities have increased.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, if you get assigned additional responsibilities, you need to be compensated accordingly.

Do not delay the discussion for too long, as soon as your boss gets used to you doing more work for same peanuts you getting now, raise is practically impossible.

Ideally you should have had this question in one form or the other at the 
time of new duties assignment.

At least that would have opened the door for more definitive discussion within a week.